# scss variable returning null

Tags: css, variables, sass

```css
// variables.scss
html {

    &.light-theme {
        $primary-1: #3BB4C1;
        $primary-2: #3AAEBB;
        $primary-3: #35A0AC;
        $secondary-1: #E3E3E3;
        $secondary-2: #E0E0E0;
        $secondary-3: #D6D6D6;
        $subtle-1: #F6F5F5;
        $subtle-2: #EDECEC;
        $subtle-3: #E8E8E8;
    }
}

// styles.scss
@import "variables.scss";

html {
    background-color: $subtle-1;
}

// Compilation Error
// Error: Undefined variable: "$subtle-1".
//         on line 10 of sass/e:\Projects\newTab\client\styles\style\style.scss
// >>   background-color: $subtle-1;
//    -------------------^
```

i hade a varaibles.scss file that store all my varaibles. Style.scss store the code for style the html page. I had imported the file but the variables are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined block-scoped variables. Here is what the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#scope) says about those:

> Variables declared in blocks (curly braces in SCSS or indented code in Sass) are usually local, and can only be accessed within the block they were declared.

Which means as soon as you put them into a block, they cannot be exported to another file. You need to put the variables to the global scope to be able to import it in another file:

**variables.scss**:

```
$subtle-1: #F6F5F5;
...
```

**styles.scss**:

```
@import "variables";

html {
    background-color: $subtle-1;
}
```

Or even better, use the [new module system](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use):

```
@use "variables";

html {
    background-color: variables.$subtle-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, you write your variables wrong inside classes.
As the doc mention that:

> Variables declared at the top level

```
$primary-1: #3BB4C1;
$primary-2: #3AAEBB;
$primary-3: #35A0AC;
$secondary-1: #E3E3E3;
$secondary-2: #E0E0E0;
$secondary-3: #D6D6D6;
$subtle-1: #F6F5F5;
$subtle-2: #EDECEC;
$subtle-3: #E8E8E8;
```